# MSSQL get rows which only differ at 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, where-clause

I have a task on which I have no idea how that could even work out.

I have to find records, which have a time difference of X and where a boolean is ON/OFF. I tried to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and used the conditions in the ON clause, but it gave me the wrong result.

So my question is, how can I select rows, which have the same value in 2 columns, but different values in other 2 columns?

Edit:
My problem is, that for some reason my actual query returns the same entry multiple times. I checked if the entry exists multiple times, but it doesn't

---

Data for reference:

```
ID1   ID2   Boolean   Time
 1     1       0      2018-03-06 11:31:39
 1     1       1      2018-03-06 11:33:39
 2     1       0      2018-03-06 11:31:39
 2     2       1      2018-03-06 11:40:39
```

The desired output from the query would be

```
ID1   ID2   Boolean   Time
 1     1       0      2018-03-06 11:31:39
 1     1       1      2018-03-06 11:33:39
```

because ID1 and ID2 are the same, the Boolean is different and the time difference is in the specified range (lets say 5 minutes). The other 2 entries are not valid, because ID2 differs and the time difference is too big.

My current query:

```
select 
t1.id1,
t1.id2,
t1.boolean,
t1.time
from t1 t1
left outer join t1 t2
on t1.boolean != t2.boolean and datediff(minute, t1.time, t2.time)<=5
where t1.id1 = t2.id1
and t1.id2 = t2.id2
```

Comment: Your query is correct, what is the issue

Comment: What is wrong in the query? For the given data it gave the same output what you have mentioned. Just one error `and t.id2 = t2.id2` change `t` to `t1`

Comment: Change the `left join` to `inner join`, as left join is nor required here

Comment: it is due to `left join` may be change the it to `inner join` and try

Comment: Even with `inner join` I get every entry at least 2 times

Comment: Can u please share such data for which you got duplicate data

Comment: Sadly not as it is confident data, but I can tell for sure, that the entries I get are exactly the same

Comment: Can you please share the current output of duplicate record...

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine, I found few small issues

1- Table alias used is wrong instead of `t` it should be `t1`

2- Order or data is wrong

3- Changed `left join` to `inner join`

4- Modified `ON` and `Where` condition for better readability and performance

Check following corrected query.

```
WITH t1 AS 
(
 SELECT * FROM (VALUES 

 (1   ,  1     ,  0     , '2018-03-06 11:31:39'),
 (1   ,  1   ,    1    ,  '2018-03-06 11:33:39'),
 (2   ,  1   ,    0    ,  '2018-03-06 11:31:39'),
 (2   ,  2   ,    1    ,  '2018-03-06 11:40:39')
  ) T(  ID1,   ID2 ,  Boolean,   Time)
)

select 
t1.id1,
t1.id2,
t1.boolean,
t1.time
from t1 t1
inner  join t1 t2
on t1.id1 = t2.id1  and t1.id2 = t2.id2 
where 
t1.boolean != t2.boolean and datediff(minute, t1.time, t2.time)<=5
ORDER BY [TIME]
```

Output

```
+-----+-----+---------+---------------------+
| id1 | id2 | boolean | time                |
+-----+-----+---------+---------------------+
| 1   | 1   | 0       | 2018-03-06 11:31:39 |
+-----+-----+---------+---------------------+
| 1   | 1   | 1       | 2018-03-06 11:33:39 |
+-----+-----+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Seems like I have another problem then, because my query return the same entry multiple times. I even rewrote the query to include only what was given here and still multiple entries. These entries don't even differ anywhere

Comment: This is strange, for the given data and the query it should only return two rows. Did you executed the sample CTE code? What is the output

Comment: I can't share the data. The test code does give the correct result

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicate value use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT t1.id1
    ,t1.id2
    ,t1.boolean
    ,t1.TIME
FROM t1 t1
INNER JOIN t1 t2 ON t1.boolean != t2.boolean
    AND datediff(minute, t1.TIME, t2.TIME) <= 5
WHERE t1.id1 = t2.id1
    AND t1.id2 = t2.id2
GROUP BY t1.id1
    ,t1.id2
    ,t1.boolean
    ,t1.TIME
```

Comment: Grouping doesn't work as well. It does eleminate the duplicates, but the output is still wrong

Comment: It still doesn't give me the desired result for my data. I need to show what is shown in the sample output. Yet I only get 1 of these rows

Comment: How would it possible? For the given data when I apply group by it works fine and gave 2 results as expected?

Comment: It would be appreciated if you'll modify sample data in such a way we can reproduce the problem, we understand that it is confidential but you can modify the data and share with us... without proper data no one will help you

Comment: You really want sample data for 140 columns? The only reason I don't give sample data for all is the sheer amount of columns

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    D1.*
FROM
    Data AS D1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            Data AS D2
        WHERE
            D1.ID1 = D2.ID2 AND
            ~D1.Boolean = D2.Boolean AND
            ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, D1.Time, D2.Time)) <= 5)
ORDER BY
    D1.ID1,
    D1.Boolean,
    D1.Time
```